# Adobe Air SOL Location for OSX

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, cookies, air

So I currently have an air app I am working on that I plan on distributing out. One of the features I have is the ability to import other SWF's and record what happens on screen. Now on windows, users are able to take the cookies of the swf that's being imported and place them in a folder so my air app can load them. This folder for windows is:

C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming

And inside the roaming folder will be a folder with the app name, and inside is where you would place the cookie files.

However, some of my users are reporting on the OSX end that they can not find this folder anywhere. I just got off a two hour skype call with a friend of mine who uses OSX and we could not find this folder equivalent at all. We went through three pages worth of google results and can not find this. Any help is welcome, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google gave me the next result:

> Macintosh HD:Users::Library:Preferences: AIR-App-Reverse-Domain-Name:Local Store:#SharedObjects: flashname.swf\filename.so
>
> NOTE: On Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) and above (Mountain Lion etc) the
>   Library folder is hidden...

http://www.adrianparr.com/?p=19

It looks like SharedObject files of an AIR application are located inside of the [app-storage folder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a4c56-7fc6). And, maybe, it would be esier for you to get the path through the special variable:

```
File.applicationStorageDirectory + path-to-the-shared-object-directory
```